# How can I update a character's data using a text field in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android and I'm working on a character creator for a tabletop rpg. I currently have a character class and a simple display screen. What I want is to let the player click on a text box containing basic information, and freely edit it with new relevant details, and update the info in the individual character . However whenever I test this I can type on the text field but it doesn't actually update the character's data.

Right now I have

```
OutlinedTextField(
     value = character.effects,
     onValueChange = { character.effects = it },
)
```

I've also tried using a setter in onValueChange

```
fun SetEffects(newEffect: String){
    effects = newEffect
}
```

I've also tried using `remember {mutableStateOF(character.effects)}` and a lot of other variations.

Normally I'd just use a pointer but android doesn't seem to support those.

If this absolutely requires ViewModel I'm probably screwed cause I've been looking at that for a week, and can't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try below way it will work-

```
var character by remember { mutableStateOf(Character()) }
OutlinedTextField(
    value = character.effects,
    onValueChange = { effects -> character = character.copyWithEffects(effects) }
)


var character by remember { mutableStateOf(Character()) }
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = character.effects,
            onValueChange = { effects -> character = character.copyWithEffects(effects) }
        )
```

Now create own Character data class and assign the value.

```
data class Character(val effects: String = "") {
    fun copyWithEffects(effects: String = this.effects): Character {
        return Character(effects)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this solution works or not.

Comment: thanks for the response, but unless I'm misunderstanding something this doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. The TextField is updating, but the actual character data seems to stay the same. Ideally editing this TextField should change the same data displayed in other TextFields. Also I'm passing the character class from an outside function, and the remember system doesn't seem to be working with that.

please let me know if you need a larger snippet of my code. The one I provided was shortened to post easier, but that may be causing misunderstandings.